# XSD Setup for Arrays

Tags: arrays, json, xsd, soa

I have a nested json array as follows:

When I try to post this I am getting the error messages:

{"RestFaultElement":{"summary":"Translation Failure.\nFailed to translate JSON to XML. java.io.IOException: Array start inside array\nThe incoming data does not conform to the NXSD schema. Please correct the problem.\n","code":null,"detail":null}}

```
"Options": {
                "Co-ordinates": {
                    "X": "594752",
                    "Y": "714430"
            },              
                "Language": "English",                      
                "PageSize": "A4",                           
                "Scale": "1,000",                           
                "Orientation": "Landscape",                 
                "GeometryData": {                           
                    "type": "polygon",
                    "rings": [
                        [
                            [
                                716102.6700605,
                                733105.7692149
                            ],
                            [
                                716431.41550966,
                                733105.7692149
                            ],
                            [
                                716431.41550966,
                                732878.22709315
                            ],
                            [
                                716102.6700605,
                                732878.22709315
                            ],
                            [
                                716102.6700605,
                                733105.7692149
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],
                    "_ring": 0,
                    "spatialReference": {
                        "wkid": 2157,
                        "latestWkid": 2157
                    },
                    "cache": {
                        "_extent": {
                            "xmin": 717192,
                            "ymin": 733058.86,
                            "xmax": 717424,
                            "ymax": 733230.86,
                            "spatialReference": {
                                "wkid": 2157,
                                "latestWkid": 2157
                            }
                        },
                        "_partwise": "PARTWISE",
                        "_centroid": {
                            "type": "point",
                            "x": 717308.00000013,
                            "y": 733144.86000007,
                            "spatialReference": {
                                "wkid": 2157,
                                "latestWkid": 2157
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

The problem part of this seems to be with the "rings" array. 
I believe that 1 of 2 things is happening:
 1. The JSON syntax is wrong.
 2. The xsd file is set up wrong.

The XSD segments which should accept this element is defined as:

```
<xsd:element type="xsd:decimal" name="rings"/>
```

Would this set up allow for an array like so to be passed to it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing brackets at start end end of your string. Try:

```
{"rings": [
                    [
                        [
                            716102.6700605,
                            733105.7692149
                        ],
                        [
                            716431.41550966,
                            733105.7692149
                        ],
                        [
                            716431.41550966,
                            732878.22709315
                        ],
                        [
                            716102.6700605,
                            732878.22709315
                        ],
                        [
                            716102.6700605,
                            733105.7692149
                        ]
                    ]
                ]}
```

Comment: Sorry, let me edit the question so that I can include the whole piece of json